# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized Error occured when i try to download file via Web Client

Tags: c#, authentication

I have the following code running in a windows form Application:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("http://50.35.125.91:81/");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
wp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("matif", "yyy", "xyz");


client.Proxy = wp;
client.DownloadFile("http://50.35.125.91:81/abc/AppUpdate.xml", @"D:\abc.xml");
```

Each time, I get the following exception

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I know for sure the credentials are valid,

Comment: You pass credentials to your proxy but your sever also required authorization.

Answer (score 2):

Provide credentials to proxy **and** client:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("http://50.35.125.91:81/");
    wp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("matif", "yyy", "xyz");

    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = wp.Credentials;
    client.Proxy = wp;
    client.DownloadFile("http://50.35.125.91:81/abc/AppUpdate.xml", @"D:\abc.xml");
}
```

Comment: This really helped me today; I was trying to download some data from a sharepoint site and kept getting a 401 message. Specifically adding the credentials to the WebClient object worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the default credentials. The UseDefaultCredentials should be set to false instead of true:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Also this line you don't need at all:

```
wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var Client = new WebClient())
{            
   Client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("matif", "yyy", "xyz");
   Client.DownloadFile("http://50.35.125.91:81/abc/AppUpdate.xml", @"D:\abc.xml");
}
```